# Javascript get selected text from any textinput/textarea on the page

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

How can  get the selected text from a textbox/textarea if I don't know which one active (focused). I am trying to create a small bookmarklet that will correct the selected text in any type of input on a page.

Comment: I'm sorry, but can you clarify the question for me: Do you want the content of the currently focused textarea/input field or the content of a specific field regardless of the current focus?

Comment: I think this is about the *selected*, or highlighted, part of a text element or textarea value.

Comment: When do you want to get the selected text? For example, if it's on a button click or something similar, then none of the inputs or textareas will be focused.

Comment: @FishBasketGordo This is for a bookmarklet. I will click it outside the document window - on the shortcuts toolbar.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

For the selection, you want `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd`.

As for the currently focused element, use `document.activeElement`.

So as a combination you can use: http://jsfiddle.net/rBPte/1/.

As Tim Down pointed out, you'd need a more complex solution for Internet Explorer version 8 or lower: [Caret position in textarea, in characters from the start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263743/how-to-get-cursor-position-in-textarea/3373056#3373056)

```
function getText(elem) { // only allow input[type=text]/textarea
    if(elem.tagName === "TEXTAREA" ||
       (elem.tagName === "INPUT" && elem.type === "text")) {
        return elem.value.substring(elem.selectionStart,
                                    elem.selectionEnd);
        // or return the return value of Tim Down's selection code here
    }
    return null;
}

setInterval(function() {
    var txt = getText(document.activeElement);
    document.getElementById('div').innerHTML =
        txt === null ? 'no input selected' : txt;
}, 100);
```

Comment: You might want to add a bit of defensive code here, this will throw errors when you select actual elements (try highlighting the textboxes themselves and watch your console output)

Comment: `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` are not supported on IE < 9. See my answer here for a cross-browser function to work round this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263743/how-to-get-cursor-position-in-textarea/3373056#3373056

Comment: Good. How can we do with out using setInterval, using event?