# Get number of characters selected from a text inside textarea or input text

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible with pure JavaScript, to select part of a text within a  and through a function, return the number of characters that were selected?

For the example below, selecting "banana" somehow returns "Total Chars Selected: 6 chars".

```
<textarea id="my_textarea" name="my_textarea" rows="10" cols="50">Apple Banana Orange</textarea>
```

**Intended Result:**

[image: Example]

Comment: This has been closed as a duplicate, but the 'duplicate' is a different question. This asks how to count the number of characters selected - the other question asks how to count the number of characters entered.

Comment: You can use this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416020/javascript-get-selected-text-from-any-textinput-textarea-on-the-page
just use the length from the return value